# R syntax question with variable in quotes for loop

Tags: r, loops, syntax, quotes

I have

```
testusers = c(1724,1751,1860,1915,1988,2053,2102,2204,2218,2315)
```

for any one of these, I can run my recommenderlab trained model like:

```
rec <- predict(model, RLmatrix["2204"], n=5);
as (rec,"list")
```

and get

```
$`2204`
[1] "268"  "1387" "2360" "2710" "2863"
```

which is what I want.

How do I use a single command to get all ten of these?

I've can do

```
for (i in 1:10)print (testusers[i])
```

and it prints out the ten testusers, but when I replace the loop code with

```
{
    rec <- predict(model, RLmatrix[testusers[i]], n=5);
    as (rec,"list")
}
```

it throws up; likewise if I put `testusers[i]` in quotes.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience using `recommenderlab` but it seems you can do something like:

```
rec <- predict(model, RLmatrix[as.character(testusers)], n=5)
```